# Recording issue in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I'm able to access my application normally. But while recording in Google-chrome with load-runner Events are getting recorded but Application is getting hanged and not able to proceed further. I tried changing port in LR still the same issue. Provide some tips to resolve it.

I'm using HTTP protocol for recording in URL mode

Thanks

Comment: Can you try other form of recording? Firefox, proxy-recording, TruClient protocol?

Answer (score 0):

These URLs might help you in solving it

http://www.jds.net.au/tech-tips/how-to-fix-common-vugen-recording-problems/

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-LoadRunner-and-Performance/5-tips-to-solve-the-most-common-problems-seen-in-Web-recording/ba-p/6357387

Answer (score 0):

Please check the supporting browsers for your vugen version that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Go for Proxy mode recording.   Proxy mode is browser agnostic